# How to create UDF from Scala methods (to compute md5)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I would like to build one UDF from two already working functions. I'm trying to calculate a md5 hash as a new column to an existing Spark Dataframe.

```
def md5(s: String): String = { toHex(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8")))}
def toHex(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = bytes.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString("")
```

**Structure** (what i have so far)

```
val md5_hash: // UDF Implementation
val sqlfunc = udf(md5_hash)
val new_df = load_df.withColumn("New_MD5_Column", sqlfunc(col("Duration")))
```

Unfortunately i don't know how to propably implement the function as UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following `udf` function named as `md5`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def toHex(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = bytes.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString("")
def md5 = udf((s: String) => toHex(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))))

val new_df = load_df.withColumn("New_MD5_Column", md5(col("Duration")))
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not using the built-in [md5](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@md5(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function?

> **md5(e: Column): Column** Calculates the MD5 digest of a binary column and returns the value as a 32 character hex string.

You could then use it as follows:

```
val new_df = load_df.withColumn("New_MD5_Column", md5($"Duration"))
```

You have to make sure that the column is of binary type so in case it's int you may see the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'md5(`Duration`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type, however, '`Duration`' is of int type.;;

You should then change the type to be `md5`-compatible, i.e. binary type, using [bin](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@bin(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **bin(e: Column): Column** An expression that returns the string representation of the binary value of the given long column. For example, `bin("12")` returns `"1100"`.

A solution could be as follows then:

```
val solution = load_df.
  withColumn("bin_duration", bin($"duration")).
  withColumn("md5", md5($"bin_duration"))
scala> solution.show(false)
+--------+------------+--------------------------------+
|Duration|bin_duration|md5                             |
+--------+------------+--------------------------------+
|1       |1           |c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|
+--------+------------+--------------------------------+
```

You could also "chain" functions together and do the conversion and calculating MD5 in one `withColumn`, but I prefer to keep steps separate in case there's an issue to resolve and having intermediate steps usually helps.

### Performance

The reason why you would consider using the build-in functions `bin` and `md5` over custom user-defined functions (UDFs) is that you *could* get a better performance as Spark SQL is in full control and *would* not add extra steps for serialization to and deserialization from an internal row representation.

[image]

It is not the case here, but still requires less to import and work with.

Comment: Already tried this but  I get the following error: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'md5(`Duration`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type, however, '`Duration`' is of int type.;;`

Comment: The hashing functions only work on Strings, as far as I know, but the conversion shouldn't be an issue - sadly it's not implicitly handled.

Comment: Actually the [comments](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2222) mention that it works on `Binary` type but I've found it to work with `String` as well