# How to run udf on every column in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a UDF:

```
val TrimText = (s: AnyRef) => {
    //does logic returns string
}
```

And a dataframe:

```
var df = spark.read.option("sep", ",").option("header", "true").csv(root_path + "/" + file)
```

I would like to perform `TrimText` on every value in every column in the dataframe.

However, the problem is, I have a dynamic number of columns. I know I can get the list of columns by `df.columns`.  But I am unsure on how this will help me with my issue.  How can I solve this problem?

TLDR Issue - Performing a UDF on every column in a dataframe, when the dataframe has an unknown number of columns

---

Attempting to use:

```
df.columns.foldLeft( df )( (accDF, c) =>
  accDF.withColumn(c, TrimText(col(c)))
)
```

Throws this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
accDF.withColumn(c, TrimText(col(c)))
```

`TrimText` is suppose to return a string and expects the input to be a value in a column.  So it is going to be standardizing every value in every row of the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foldLeft` to traverse the column list to iteratively apply `withColumn` to the DataFrame using your UDF:

```
df.columns.foldLeft( df )( (accDF, c) =>
  accDF.withColumn(c, TrimText(col(c)))
)
```

Comment: @test acc, you need to wrap `TrimText ` inside `udf()` to make it a UDF.  I'm also assuming the function has the necessary logic to handle various data types.

Comment: Throws similar error, `withColumn` is expecting a string value in its second parameter while `udf(TrimText(col(c)))` returns a `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction` object

Comment: The way you apply `udf()` is incorrect.  You either directly define `trimText` as `udf( (...) => ... )`; or define `val trimTextUdf = udf(trimText)` and use it like `trimTextUdf(col(c))`

Comment: @testacc: This is the best way to do it. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819019/how-to-create-udf-from-scala-methods-to-compute-md5 for an example of how the UDF should be created and applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(("1 "," 2"),(" 3","4"))).toDF()
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def TrimText(s: Column): Column = {
//does logic returns string
  trim(s)
}
a.select(a.columns.map(c => TrimText(col(c))):_*).show
```

Comment: `trim` function in spark is not the same as `TrimText` function I have created, the function might be poorly named, it is NOT the same thing.

Comment: but that does not matter if you want to operate anything on the column pass your parameter like this and return type will be column

Comment: Okay.  I attempted your solution and this error was thrown - ```error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
  df = df.select(df.columns.map(c => TrimText(col(c))) : _*)```

Comment: please share your trimtext function logic and it’s return type should be a column

Comment: It's proprietary.  It returns a string.  I am expecting a column value (String). So if I have a million records and 5 columns.  This function will be called 5 million times, once every value of every record on every column.  Output will always be a string,

Comment: String goes in, string goes out.  Though the function accepts `anyref` for some oddball cases and then converts to string.  But just assume it is always a string going in

Comment: can you please open a chat, trying to understand in your case a column object is going in rt ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179584/discussion-between-chandan-ray-and-test-acc).

Answer (score 0):

```
>> I would like to perform TrimText on every value in every column in the dataframe.
>> I have a dynamic number of columns.
```

when sql function is available for trimming why UDF, could see below code fit's for you ?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.udf.register("TrimText", (x:String) =>  ..... )

val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(
  (26, true, 60000.00),
  (32, false, 35000.00)
)).toDF("age", "education", "income")

val cols2 = df2.columns.toSet
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

val query = "select " + buildcolumnlst(cols2) + " from table1 "
println(query)
val dfresult = spark.sql(query)
dfresult.show()

def buildcolumnlst(myCols: Set[String]) = {
  myCols.map(x => "TrimText(" + x + ")" + " as " + x).mkString(",") 
}
```

results,

```
select trim(age) as age,trim(education) as education,trim(income) as income from table1 
+---+---------+-------+
|age|education| income|
+---+---------+-------+
| 26|     true|60000.0|
| 32|    false|35000.0|
+---+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Because `TrimText` does infinetly more then just `trim` the text.  It is just what it is named.  Out of my control.

Comment: alright, then instead of sql function " trim " you can patch the UDF function in the method "buildcolumnlst" over there. (did an EDIT on the above code)